# Order column by custom pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order an invoice data column. The invoices codification field is composed by:

1. A capital letter (eg. A-Z)
2. Actual year (eg. 19)
3. Backslash (/)
4. Invoice number (eg. 100)

**Real example: F19/1234**

At this moment I was using the following query to order by invoice codification

```
select * from `invoices` 
order by LENGTH(codification) desc, `codification` desc
```

That was working for invoices from 2019, the issue is that invoices number for 2020 are reseted to 0, so this ordering is failing.

Now I have the following

- F19/102
- F19/101
- F19/100
- F20/1
- F20/0

Any ideas on how to order them descending by year and invoice number?

I have tried to order by REGEX_SUBSTRING but this is no working, I think that this query does nothing...

```
select * from `invoices` 
order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(`codification`, '[0-9]+(?=\/)') desc, REGEXP_SUBSTR(`codification`, '([a-z0-9_-]*[\/]?)$') desc
```

The order I wanted to accomplish is (desc by year and invoice nº)

- F20/1
- F20/0
- F19/102
- F19/101
- F19/100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
order by codification desc
```

You will have a problem when the invoice numbers for 2020 exceed 10.  To handle that:

```
order by substring_index(codification, '/', 1),
         substring_index(codification, '/', -1) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to order directly by the elements. E.g. `order by year desc, invoice_number desc`?

Possibly you need to add the element for the capital letter too.